# What specific languages does the character encoding EUC-JP cover?

Tags: character-encoding

I want to know what very specific languages the encoding EUC-JP actually cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Japanese.

Longer answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-JP

Comment: what is the languages supported in the long answer since your link kind of confused me:(

Comment: what languages are JIS X 0208, JIS X 0212, and JIS X 0201 are they all Japanese? If so what kind of Japanese?

Comment: They are Japanese character sets. The largest one is JIS 0212, which has (quoting from Wikipedia): 21 Greek characters with diacritics,
26 Eastern European characters with diacritics (mostly Cyrillic),
198 alphabetic characters with diacritics, and
5,801 kanji. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0212#Features

Comment: It's really messy. If you're looking to _pick_ an encoding to use, just go with [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8).

Comment: Note that the different JIS definitions include characters such as ASCII, along with accented Roman characters, half-width, full-width, and various non-character symbols. So you could use it to write English, or French, etc., on a Japanese computer.

Comment: That still confuses the hell out of me but I guess the short answer is best:)

Comment: So what languages does UTF-8 cover?

Comment: Everything in the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) standard. That's going to be more-or-less everything you want (including 70,000+ Han characters), as long as you don't want, for example, older or alternative forms of kanji.

Answer (score 1):

EUC-JP was, of course, designed for Japanese, so includes all the essential Japanese characters:

- 22/64 of CJK Symbols and Punctuation
- 87/96 of Hiragana
- 90/96 of Katakana
- 12157/20992 of CJK Unified Ideographs [Kanji]
- 155/240 of Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms

But it supports Western scripts as well:

- 128/128 of Basic Latin [ASCII]
- 82/128 of Latin-1 Supplement
- 120/128 of Latin Extended-A
- 17/208 of Latin Extended-B
- 6/80 of Spacing Modifier Letters
- 71/144 of Greek and Coptic
- 92/256 of Cyrillic
- 15/112 of General Punctuation
- 4/80 of Letterlike Symbols
- 6/112 of Arrows
- 32/256 of Mathematical Operators
- 1/256 of Miscellaneous Technical
- 32/128 of Box Drawing
- 12/96 of Geometric Shapes
- 7/256 of Miscellaneous Symbols

  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_
  `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¦§¨©ª¬®¯°±´¶¸º¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍ
  ÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎ
  ďĐđĒēĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŐőŒœŔŕ
  ŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǵˇ˘˙˚
  ˛˝΄΅ΆΈΉΊΌΎΏΐΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυ
  φχψωϊϋόύώЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзи
  йклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяёђѓєѕіїјљњћќўџ‐―‖‘’“”†‡‥…‰′″※℃№™Å←↑→↓⇒⇔
  ∀∂∃∇∈∋−√∝∞∠∧∨∩∪∫∬∴∵∽≒≠≡≦≧≪≫⊂⊃⊆⊇⊥⌒─━│┃┌┏┐┓└┗┘┛├┝┠┣┤┥┨┫┬┯┰┳┴┷┸┻┼
  ┿╂╋■□▲△▼▽◆◇○◎●◯★☆♀♂♪♭♯

So you could use EUC-JP to write not only Japanese, but also English, Spanish, French, German, Greek, Russian, etc. (but *not* Arabic or Hebrew).

It's hard to answer the question of exactly which languages are "supported" because of ambiguities about exactly which characters are required for a language (e.g., Does Dutch *need* the Ĳ ligature, or is "IJ" adequate?  Are "café" and "jalapeño" English words?)